Why do i get a `'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'walk'` exception?
Why do i get a 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'walk' exception?
from pathlib import Path
p = Path()
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in p.walk():
    print(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)


Path.walk was added in Python 3.12, so you propably using an older version.
You can check the version in python with:
import sys
print(sys.version)

Instead, use os.walk or Path.glob() (or update your Python)
